# Permission denied - /usr/local/bin/pkill.pl

Tags: unix, homebrew

I'm installing Homebrew and when I run `brew doctor` it prompts:

`Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/bin/pkill.pl`

I've tried:
`$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/pkill.pl` (also other options: 777, a-x, ...I don't know which is need it for brew)

but when `ls`, still:

`ls: ./pkill.pl: Permission denied
lrwx------    1 root            wheel        23 11 feb  2012 pkill.pl
...`

Could you tell me how to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: are you installing as root?

Comment: No, I though that using sudo would be enough...

Comment: should be. see what you get by running `homebrew` as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first character in the directory listing (`l`) means the file is a symbolic link to another file. Use `ls -l` to find out which. It's most likely the permissions on that file that are the problem. The permissions for links are normally 755 (read and execute all users and write for owner).

Comment: Thank you @Dunes. I've tried `ls -l` and still.. see and example:          `lrwxr-xr-x    1 root            wheel        61 12 oct 16:46 pip-2.7 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip-2.7`
`lrwxr-xr-x    1 mcasandrariera  admin        42  8 dic 13:07 pkg-config -> ../Cellar/pkg-config/0.27.1/bin/pkg-config`

`ls: ./pkill.pl: Permission denied`
`lrwx------    1 root            wheel        23 11 feb  2012 pkill.pl`
`-rwxr-xr-x    1 root            wheel       452  3 abr  2011 pphs`

Comment: Sorry... don't know how to introduce new line separation in comments, but the idea is that, for those I have permissions, the original file to which is linked is shown

Comment: I didn't realise homebrew was a package manager. You need to be running any package manager was root (eg. `sudo brew doctor`). You do not want any user other than root to be able to use pkill, or any user (malicious code) could arbitrarily kill processes on your computer.

Comment: Thanks @Dunes and @X.Jacobs. Running `sudo brew doctor`gave now error (only warning to update Xcode, which is on going...).

Answer (score -2):

This should work  `sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin/pkill.pl`